# Implementing a custom login in asp.net Mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am just starting to use `ASP.Net MVC5` and I am having a little challenge.
I have an already built system that uses `WebForms` and I am migrating it to `MVC`.

I understand that `MVC` provides an `Authentication` and `Authorization` provider, but I want to implement a simple login based on the database I already have.
In my previous system, when a user logs in, the id and role of the user is stored in a session variable and checked across all pages. The id is also used for some tasks in the app.
Is there a way to use `MVC Identity Management` with my existing database?

I tried the following from a previous post but can't seem to get it working.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
  if (new UserManager.IsValid(username, password))
  {
      var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
      new[] { 
               // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
               new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,username),

                // optionally you could add roles if any
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "RoleName"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AnotherRole"),

            },
      DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

      HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
      new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);
      return RedirectToAction("MyAction"); // auth succeed 
  }
  // invalid username or password
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid username or password");
  return View();
}

class UserManager
{
   public bool IsValid(string username, string password)
   {
       using(var db=new MyDbContext()) // use your DbConext
       {
          // if your users set name is Users
          return db.Users.Any(u=>u.Username==username 
                              && u.Password==password); 
       }
    }
 }
```

Please any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into using the UserManager? You can get the current user logged in details, create users etc etc

Comment: I created the `UserManager` as a class and tried to use it, but errors were shown on the controller class.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: this may help : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, thanks. I have succeeded in getting rid of the errors and I can login, but, after login in, I am not able access controllers that I have given the [Authorize].

Comment: Thanks @AnupamSingh

Comment: @elfico This is probably because you're not Authorized to get into that controller. Check if you have the correct roles.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, I used a simple [Authorize] verb. I didnt specify it for a role. Also, for this piece of code `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(` , I couldnt get HttpContext to work, so I changed it to :  `IOwinContext context = new OwinContext();   context.Authentication.SignIn(`

Comment: @elfico Okay, i think the authorize tag just checks to see if youre signed in. I don't believe it will work if you have made a custom log in